# C# . Find custom tag in text

Tags: c#, regex

Plain text contains a custom tag that named <code>. Inside a tag there is plain text or XML.

For example:

```
bla-bla-bla  
    <code lang="cs">
        public static void main(){}
    </code>
bla-bla-bla
```

or

```
bla-bla-bla
    <code lang="xaml">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Click Me"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </code>
bla-bla-bla
```

I need to find all <code> tags with content using regular expression.

Comment: Is there a reason to parse a raw string w/ RegEx rather than use XMLDocument? I guess more to my point - is the "bla-bla-bla" also markup or could it be any text?

Comment: Raw string is not valid xml document

Comment: I would rather use XPath. It's meant for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me (you need to turn on Singleline for that to work):

```
<code[^>]*>(.*?)<\/code>
```

Comment: but you must have "Single-line-mode" turned on

Comment: your correction is wrong.. it's not the multiline-mode (/m) it's the singleline-mode (/s): /<code[^>]*>(.*?)<\/code>/s

Answer (score 0):

Take this code if you don't want to use singleline-mode explicitly:

```
<code[^>]*>((?:.|\n|\r)*?)<\/code>
```

[See test here](http://regexpr.com/?pattern=/%3Ccode%5B%5E%3E%5D%2a%3E%28%28?%3a.%7C%5Cn%7C%5Cr%29%2a?%29%3C%5C/code%3E/&subject=bla-bla-bla%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccode%20lang=%22xaml%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStackPanel%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CButton%20Content=%22Click%20Me%22/%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/StackPanel%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/code%3E%0D%0Abla-bla-bla)